# How to watch directory for file modifications

Tags: python, macos, bash, launchd

I'm on a mac. I've been using Launchd's WatchPaths directive to watch a directory for file changes. My script only triggers when a file is added or deleted from the watched directory.

However, the script does not trigger when a file is modified..

Essentially, I'm trying to create a DIY Dropbox for syncing my Sites folder.

Is there a way to do this via launchd, bash or python?

I think linux has something like inotify, but I am not aware of a solution for mac.

Comment: Ideally, I don't want to poll for changes every n seconds...

Comment: The only solution I'm aware of involves polling. An example of the method I was going to suggest can be found here: https://github.com/jessemiller/HamlPy/blob/2e029110b6ab2f502439634ded7a781b4a521cfe/hamlpy/hamlpy_watcher.py#L28 -- I'm interested to see if anyone can provide an alternative!

Comment: MacOS supports FreeBSD-style `kqueue`, which is similar to `inotify` in various ways.  How to actually get it to work, I have no idea. :-)

Comment: https://github.com/mynyml/watchr is the de-facto standard for this sort of thing in the Ruby world. For OS X, it relies on https://github.com/sandro/ruby-fsevent , a Ruby extension exposing the OS X FSEvent API. A search on PyPI reveals a Python equivalent: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MacFSEvents/0.2.1 -- perhaps this might be the way to go?

Comment: Maybe [Watchdog](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog]) will do what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried my hand at the problem, using the [MacFSEvents](https://github.com/malthe/macfsevents)
package ([available on PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MacFSEvents), too):

```
import os

from fsevents import Observer, Stream


def callback(file_event):
    print file_event.name # the path of the modified file


def main():
    observer = Observer()
    observe_path = os.getcwd() # just for this example
    stream = Stream(callback, observe_path, file_events=True)
    observer.start()
    observer.schedule(stream)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This will call `callback` any time a file is created, modified, or deleted (you can check which event occurred using the value of `file_event.mask`).

Note that you will probably want to observe on a thread outside of the main thread (the above program refuses to quit, even on `KeyboardInterrupt`). More information on the API can be found in the MacFSEvents README. Hope this helps!

Comment: This totally helps! I'm not familiar with threads though.. Any pointers for learning more about it or observing a different thread?

Comment: JoeFish recommended [Watchdog](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog), maybe that takes care of the particulars? Otherwise, check out [these](http://www.artfulcode.net/articles/multi-threading-python/) [articles](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/).